# How to Mass Update(Edit) in Laravel Query Builder?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Hello guys I am trying to do a mass update for my application using a checkbox but when I try to update it will just update the 1st student id(I tried to select other students the update does not work). Could you give some insights or concrete examples I can follow?

This is what I have tried so far

```
public function changeSched()
{
  
    DB::table('class_list')
        ->whereIn('id',  $this->selectedStudents)
        ->update(['section' => $this->selectedSched]);


}
```

For my checkbox

```
@foreach($classlist as $stud)
                <tr>
                  <th class="bg-white py-5 px-5">
                    <div class="items-center">
                      
                      <input type="checkbox" wire:model="selectedStudents.{{ $stud->id }}"/>
                    </div>
                    </th>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see any error in your update statement so it should update all the records provided by the query (mass updates are documented [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-updates)).

I guess the error is before, when you set `$this->selectedStudents`. Are you sure that this variable contains a simple array (not an associative array) with all the selected IDs?

You should do the following:

- Debug the `$this->selectedStudents` variable to ensure its content is correct
- Temporarily replace it by a hardcoded value `[1, 2, 3]` to ensure that the rest of your code is appropriately working

## UPDATE

To convert `$this->selectedStudents` in the right format, you can do the following:

```php
$selectedIds = [];
foreach ($this->selectedStudents as $id => $isSelected){
    if ($isSelected) {
        $selectedIds[] = $id;
    }
}
DB::table('class_list')
        ->whereIn('id',  $selectedIds)
        ->update(['section' => $this->selectedSched]);
```

Comment: So I tried to dd() selectedStudents it returns an array starting from 0=>false 1=>false.

Comment: So it confirms that the format of selectedStudents var does not comply with the format expected by whereIn method. You will have to convert your variable into an array only containing the selected ids as values and not as keys.

Comment: the selectedStudents variable is only used twice in my code.

Comment: Can you show me how to that? I am quite new to laravel.

Comment: I updated my answer with the conversion between both formats.